# jsoncpp: Filling member of array from the code

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I looked up the code example at [jsoncpp](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/). For member array i.e "plug-ins" in json data below

```
{
    // Default encoding for text
    "encoding" : "UTF-8",

    // Plug-ins loaded at start-up
    "plug-ins" : [
        "python",
        "c++",
        "ruby"
        ],

    // Tab indent size
    "indent" : { "length" : 3, "use_space": true }
}
```

they have not demonstrated  a code snippet way to fill it from inside a program. Any one knows how to do it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All these nodes are of type [`Json::Value`](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_value.html#7e49ac977e4bcf59745a09d426669f75). You need to invoke [`Value & Json::Value::append (const Value & value)`](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_value.html#7e49ac977e4bcf59745a09d426669f75) To append an item into another.

While constructing a value object you pass type of Value which s an Enum [`Json::ValueType`](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/namespace_json.html#7d654b75c16a57007925868e38212b4e) and there is `arrayValue` in that enum.

Comment: seems like append function also takes char * .

Comment: Its not `append` takes `const char*` Its `Json::Value` constructor that takes `const char*`